# How to use accessor.set(record, value) method of record_accessor plugin helper in fluentd?

Tags: ruby, fluentd

I'm trying to use the `set` method of `record_accessor` plugin helper in fluentd for my custom filter plugin as indicated in the fluentd documentation here(https://docs.fluentd.org/plugin-helper-overview/api-plugin-helper-record_accessor#record_accessor_create-param).

But I'm getting following error, saying that the method `set` is not defined for class `Accessor` (although both methods `call` and `delete` are working just fine as mentioned in the doc):

```
error_class=NoMethodError error="undefined method `set' for #<Fluent::PluginHelper::RecordAccessor::Accessor:0x00007f05a92953c8>\nDid you mean?  send"
```

This is my plugin code(ruby) snippet that is failing:

```rb
jsonpath = '$.x'
accessor = record_accessor_create(jsonpath)


record = {'x'=>'X', 'y'=>'Y'}
value = 'AXE'
accessor.set(record, value) # throws
```

My fluentd version is **v1.6**.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: v1.6 doesn't implement a `set` method. See: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/v1.6/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/record_accessor.rb.

Comment: Here's its implementation in the `master` branch: https://github.com/fluent/fluentd/blob/36d017deb6b37a55833691edbab8d5f31353ac36/lib/fluent/plugin_helper/record_accessor.rb#L80-L82